# Remap CTRL-A in command line mode

Tags: vim

How can I remap my CTRL-A to CTRL-Q in the command line mode?

I use VIM within Tmux session (which has CTRL-A set as a prefix). When I try to insert all files which names match the pattern (i.e. for :bd command) I have to press CTRL-A twice (as it's also a prefix for tmux). I would like to use one key stroke `<C-a>` for that.

I've tried to put `cnoremap <C-q> <C-a>` to my .vimrc but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you want the `<c-a>` to do in cmd mode? I don't understand.

Comment: Today I learned a new command. Thank you. You could also disable your terminal flow control by running `stty -ixon` (in your `~/.bashrc`) which would allow you to use the `<c-s>`/`<c-q>` keys

Comment: Thank you @PeterRincker, I wasn't aware this key controls terminal flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me; note that in the terminal, `Ctrl-S` and `Ctrl-Q` are special sequences for flow control. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648237/ctrls-horizontal-split-not-working-with-command-t-in-vim) for how to unconfigure that, or use another left-hand side for your mapping, e.g. `<C-g>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for letting me know that  is special key, I wasn't aware of that.

In that case I decided to use different key (`<C-b>`). Key map for that:

```
cnoremap <C-b> <C-a>
```

I know that `<C-b>` is for scrolling but I guess in command line mode it should be ok to use that key.